# Dot product between row vectors by MMULT not working in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel to do some dot product between two row vectors:

```
=MMULT(B1049:M1049, TRANSPOSE(B1050:M1050))
```

But it does not work, as the cell for the formula shows "#VALUE!". I wonder why? Thanks!

Note that all the cells in "B1049:M1049" and "B1050:M1050"  are numbers.

PS: Is this question more suitable here or Superuser?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to enter `MMULT` as an **array** formula, not as a standard formula

rather then hit enter when you type the formula in pres
ctrl-shift-enter
and excel will enter it as an array

it will end up looking like
`{=MMULT(B1049:M1049, TRANSPOSE(B1050:M1050))}`

(please note you can't enter the {} manually)

You may want to look at Excel help which covers this well

Comment: Thanks! Where can I locate Excel help in Excel 2007? Or/and some online information?

Comment: No probs, thx for the quick accept :) . (1) In Excel Press F1 and type MMULT. Or (2) click on your MMULT function and press Shift-F3 togther to bring up the function wizard for MMULT which has a help hyperlink

Answer (score 14):

probably simpler, you can just use =SUMPRODUCT(vec1,vec2).
This is exactly the Euclidean inner product, without resorting to array formulas.

Comment: In the statement of the question, I don't see the word matrix anywhere, but I do see dot product, but the intent is up to the OP, so I cannot argue!  Either way, a nice lesson in using array functions is shared, but I wanted to share a more lightweight and direct solution to the problem.

Comment: Here is another source explaining it: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/17929-vector-dot-product.html